# Override json encoding in rest api

Tags: uploads, headers, rest-api

I'm trying to create a secure download plugin.

I found the rest api the best option for this task, but i cant change headers like `Content-Type:`. In the `register_rest_route` callback these headers already set.
If i set `Content-disposition: attachment, filename=asd.txt` i get `ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION` in chrome.

I know rest is not meant to handle these tasks, but i couldn't find any alternatives. If there is, pls tell me about it.

The data downloaded seems like it's json encoded.

I'm sick of wordpress "magic". These tasks would be so easy using plain PHP but wordpress just makes it complicated.

Please someone tell me how to disable these magic headers *** or recommend me a way for secured (php) downloads in my plugin.

(No, i don't want to use third party plugins. I've tried many of them. None of them worked so far... :D These whole wordpress thing is a huge step backwards after symfony...)

Here is my **experimental** code:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('secure-downloads/v1', '/download/(?P<filename>.*)', 
    array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'secure_downloads_handle_download'
    ));
});
function secure_downloads_handle_download(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    $filename = urldecode($request->offsetGet('filename'));
    if(strpos($filename, '/..'))
    {
        return new WP_REST_Response('', 403);
    }
    $path = SECURE_DOWNLOADS_UPLOAD_DIR . $filename;
    return new WP_REST_Response(file_get_contents($path), 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'Binary',
        'Content-disposition' => 'attachment, filename=\\' . $filename . '\\'
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what  i found out:

The `ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION` error was the bad composition of the `Content-Disposition` header. Here is the correct one:

```
array(
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'
)
```

Note the **semicolon** after attachment, the **doublequotes** around the filename and the **capital D** in disposition word as @Tom J Nowell pointed out.

This solved the headers problem but the `WP_REST_Response` still outputs the files like they were json encoded. So i went the conventional way:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
readfile($path);
exit;
```

Comment: It's interesting because I don't think JSON has anything to do with REST :) so why encoding all responses as JSON and not allow changing it via semantic methods? Crazy... Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to add the content disposition field.

But specifically it's Content-**D**isposition not Content-**d**isposition

I would also add some validation to your filename parameter thats being passed to `file_get_contents` to ensure it exists and it's valid. Else you might be vulnerable to directory traversal attacks or remote URL requests

Comment: I will try the capital. This could be the error. Thx. Yeah, i know about the validation thing. Thats why i wrote experimental code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook for exactly this situation that avoids prematurely stopping script execution, and maintains WP's handling of `HEAD` method requests. Put something similar to this in your REST response handler function:

```php
$your_served = false;
$your_content = $something;

add_filter(
    'rest_pre_serve_request',
    function($served, $result, $request, $rest_server) use (&$your_served, &$your_content) {
        if (!$served) {
            if ($your_served) {
                $served = $your_served;
            }
            else {
                add_filter(
                    'rest_pre_echo_response',
                    function($result, $rest_server, $request) use (&$your_served, &$your_content) {
                        # serve $your_content here but do not return or exit, in this case readfile() would be optimal
                        $your_served = true;
                        return null; # explicitly prevent WP sending the normal JSON response
                    },
                    10, # change priority to suit
                    3
                );
            }
        }
        return $served;
    },
    10, # change priority to suit
    4
);

$result = new WP_REST_Response();
$result->set_headers([
    'Content-Type' => $your_content_type,
    # you may include others such as 'Content-Length'
]);
return $result;
```