# Wordpress Rest API custom endpoint for RSS feed

Tags: rest-api, rss, feed, endpoints

I know how to register custom endpoints for Wordpress REST API and actually use it to output podcasts from my website like this:

```
register_rest_route( 'myradio/v1', '/podcasts/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'myradio_podcasts_api_endpoint',
    'args' => array(
        'id' => array(
            'description' => esc_html__( 'Unique identifier for the object.', 'myradio' ),
            'type'        => 'integer',
            'prop_format' => 'int64',
            'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            },
        ),
    ),
));
```

Now I want to register an additional route to allow users to subscribe to my podcasts. For that I offer a RSS feed with the same data, right now as a custom link using a wordpress template, setting the header as *Content-Type: application/rss+xml*.

To integrate this functionality directly in the REST API I want to register a RSS feeds endpoint adding **/rss** to the route with something like that:

```
register_rest_route( 'myradio/v1', '/podcasts/(?P<id>\d+/rss)', .array(...) );
```

Where and how do I define the response content type as **application/rss+xml**?

When I tried to echo the RSS feed directly at my callback function, the browser complains about an not well-formed document because the header is application/json.

Comment: If your podcast is a CPT or a taxonomy term, you could just visit its archive and put `/feed` on the end of the URL? You shouldn't need any code to do that, WP does it out of the box

Comment: Great info, that works out for most cases. But for some there is no base taxonomy or CPT. Any chance to create a custom rss endpoint? I think of another situation where I need a geojson endpoint to show them on a map. So finally the question is about how to create a endpoint with a different Response Content Type as described in OpenAPI with _responses.<code>.content.<media-type>_.

Comment: That's a different Q to what you asked, just know that making a REST API endpoint respond with an RSS feed is not a good idea, it should respond with a REST response, aka JSON

Comment: REST response normally doesn't mean exclusively JSON, but ok, I read now that Wordpress understands REST exclusivly as sending and receiving data as JSON. So the first comment to my question should be the accepted answer right?

Comment: You can make it respond with something other than JSON, but it's a weird thing to do, adding `/feed` to the end of a REST API endpoint in WP won't turn it into an RSS though. Keep in mind these aren't answers, they're comments. You should details exactly what podcasts are stored as in your Q, otherwise adding the feed URL modifier is the normal answer ( though this doesn't apply in your case, I'm assuming you're using a custom table to store these )

Comment: I have a custom structure with chapters and podcasts being CPTs, but chapters belong to podcasts and so can't automatically be filtered because I need all chapters belonging to one specific podcast. But I see now that the easiest solution is to add a taxonomy to chapters which represents the podcast it belongs to. In that way I can use built in CP feed functionality of taxonomy terms. If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override json encoding in rest api](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272386/override-json-encoding-in-rest-api)

Comment: Since the specific `Content-Type` is not the issue, but rather how to override it in general, I've flagged this as a duplicate. However, here's my answer at the earlier question (that I use myself): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/386882/27856 The currently accepted answer (mostly) works _in spite of_ the REST API, rather than _with_ it.