# Hiding API routes list

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

When you go to `/wp-json` or `/wp-json/[namespace]` on an API-enabled WordPress site, it shows all of the API routes and endpoints.

How can I disable this behaviour without disabling the REST API?

Comment: These are WP_REST_Server (wp-includes\rest-api\class-wp-rest-server.php) get_index() and get_namespace_index(). Worst case you can hook the two filters at the end of each, rest_index and rest_namespace_index, and just drop all the content (or maybe [you can use WP_REST_RESPONSE to return 404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/312034/3276)), but there's hopefully a better way.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this? It only shows the routes you're allowed to access, if there's an endpoint that requires administrator level priviledges, it will only be listed for administrators. It's not a list of every endpoint, it's a list of every endpoint **you** specifically have access to, so you gain nothing security-wise by hiding it

Answer (score 4):

Slightly modified function from @mirado (the [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_index/) has to return WP_REST_Response instance not an array)

```
    function hide_ns_and_routes( $response ) {
      $data = $response->get_data();
      $data['namespaces'] = [];
      $data['routes'] = [];
      $response->set_data( $data );

      return $response;
     }
     add_filter( 'rest_index', 'hide_ns_and_routes' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter hook 'rest_index' :

```
add_filter('rest_index', function ($response) {
  $data = $response->get_data();

  $data['namespaces'] = [];
  $data['routes'] = [];

  return $data;
}, 9999, 1);
```

It is possible to remove your route from $data['namespaces'] and $data['routes']

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers can hide the index display for `/wp-json`, but it doesn't seem to work for `/wp-json/[namespace]`.

In order to hide the index of a particular namespace, the `rest_namespace_index` hook needs to be used.

```
add_filter('rest_namespace_index', function ($response) {
    $data = $response->get_data();
    $data['namespaces'] = [];
    $data['routes'] = [];
    $response->set_data($data);

    return $response;
});
```

If someone wants to completely rewrite the routing output, or wants more flexible permissions control, a better approach would be to re-register the root routing path for that namespace

Unfortunately, `register_rest_route` is of little use at this point, as it will reject empty routing paths. Therefore, the rewrite needs to be done directly using the underlying `WP_REST_Server::register_route`.

```
rest_get_server()->register_route($namespace, "/$namespace", [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'permission_callback' => fn () => current_user_can('import'),
    'callback' => fn ($r) => $this->representationBrowser($r),
], true);
```

Note that:

1. The value of the `route` parameter should be `/[namespace]`, not `/`.
2. The `override` parameter may need to be `true`